# jQuery usage in background page of chrome extension

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

**Goal**

I am trying to use this boilerplate code to look up using a dictionary API online to find the selected word and return the definition.

**Problem**

I have tested the actual jQuery ajax call separately and it works well. Also, I can get the selected word on the page. However, for some reason I am having issues actually *calling* the ajax function within my boilerplate code in Sample.js

Advice is needed.

**background.html**

```
<html>

  <script src="jquery.js"/>
  <script src="sample.js"/>

  <body>
    <p>
    Image here:
    </p>

    <img id="target" src="white.png" width="640" height="480">

  </body>
</html>
```

**Manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Context Menus Sample",
  "description": "Shows some of the features of the Context Menus API",
  "version": "0.6",
  "permissions": ["contextMenus"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["sample.js"],
    "pages": ["background.html"]
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**Sample.js**

```
     // A generic onclick callback function.
      function genericOnClick(info, tab) {
        console.log("item " + info.menuItemId + " was clicked");
        console.log("info: " + JSON.stringify(info));
        console.log("tab: " + JSON.stringify(tab));
        alert(info.selectionText);
        displayText(info.selectionText);
      console.log("asfasdf");
      $("#testID", document).html("testing jQuery");

      $.ajax({

          url: "http://api.wordnik.com//v4/word.json/cat/definitions?api_key=mykey&includeRelated=false&includeTags=false&limit=1",
          dataType : 'json',
          success: function(data) {
            //called when successful

            alert(data[0].word);

          },
          error: function(e) {
            //called when there is an error
            console.log(e.message);
          }
        });


  }


// Create one test item for each context type.
var contexts = ["page","selection","link","editable","image","video",
                "audio"];
for (var i = 0; i < contexts.length; i++) {
  var context = contexts[i];
  var title = "Test '" + context + "' menu item";
  var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": title, "contexts":[context],
                                       "onclick": genericOnClick});
  console.log("'" + context + "' item:" + id);
}


// Create a parent item and two children.
var parent = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "Test parent item"});
var child1 = chrome.contextMenus.create(
  {"title": "Child 1", "parentId": parent, "onclick": genericOnClick});
var child2 = chrome.contextMenus.create(
  {"title": "Child 2", "parentId": parent, "onclick": genericOnClick});
console.log("parent:" + parent + " child1:" + child1 + " child2:" + child2);


// Create some radio items.
function radioOnClick(info, tab) {
  console.log("radio item " + info.menuItemId +
              " was clicked (previous checked state was "  +
              info.wasChecked + ")");
}
var radio1 = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "Radio 1", "type": "radio",
                                         "onclick":radioOnClick});
var radio2 = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "Radio 2", "type": "radio",
                                         "onclick":radioOnClick});
console.log("radio1:" + radio1 + " radio2:" + radio2);


// Create some checkbox items.
function checkboxOnClick(info, tab) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(info));
  console.log("checkbox item " + info.menuItemId +
              " was clicked, state is now: " + info.checked +
              "(previous state was " + info.wasChecked + ")");

}
var checkbox1 = chrome.contextMenus.create(
  {"title": "Checkbox1", "type": "checkbox", "onclick":checkboxOnClick});
var checkbox2 = chrome.contextMenus.create(
  {"title": "Checkbox2", "type": "checkbox", "onclick":checkboxOnClick});
console.log("checkbox1:" + checkbox1 + " checkbox2:" + checkbox2);


// Intentionally create an invalid item, to show off error checking in the
// create callback.
console.log("About to try creating an invalid item - an error about " +
            "item 999 should show up");
chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "Oops", "parentId":999}, function() {
  if (chrome.extension.lastError) {
    console.log("Got expected error: " + chrome.extension.lastError.message);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have to add permission for the url which you're calling in the ajax function to your manifest:

```
  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "http://api.wordnik.com/*"
  ],
```

Don't forget to include jquery:

```
"background": { "scripts": ["jquery.js", "sample.js"], "pages": ["background.html"] }
```

and you don't need `<script src="jquery.js"/>` in your file

The link of website should have /* at the end of it.

Comment: That's still not working - for some reason I don't think my jQuery even works at all...can anyone see anything?

Comment: Updated my answer. You forgot to include jquery in the 'scripts' property!

Comment: Got it. It's working now. Took a little debugging - I had been trying without any luck to debug from the page's console, but I realized I had to inspect the _generated_background_page.html's console to check errors.

Comment: Just informing that this is not anymore working on manifest v3.