# Google Chrome Extension: Unable to get jQuery to add html to a popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Google Chrome extension that displays a page's open graph settings in a popup.html window when someone clicks the extension's icon, but am having difficulty getting the open graph settings to appear in the popup window.

While some of my code functions - I can append an image at the top of the body section, and send an alert message - the pop up window remains empty. The console error message I receive is:

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined   background.js:1
```

My code is pasted below. I've spent the past four hours trying to figure this out, looking at numerous other SO issues like:
[Loading jQuery into chrome-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035242/loading-jquery-into-chrome-extension)
[jQuery not working in chrome extension popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33069456/jquery-not-working-in-chrome-extension-popup)
[How to load jQuery in Google Chrome Extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34831225/how-to-load-jquery-in-google-chrome-extensions)
[How to use jQuery in chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317476/how-to-use-jquery-in-chrome-extension)

If you are able to help by pointing out what I am overlooking, I'd appreciate it. Thank you!

### Manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "OG v4",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "see open graph more easily",
  "icons":{"128":"iconbig.png"},
  //"background": "popup.html",
  "browser_action": {
    "name": "OG",
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>",
    "http://*/",
    "https://*/",
    "file:///*/*",
    "https://*.google.com/"
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.google.com; object-src 'self'",

  "content_scripts": [ {
    "js": [ "jquery-2.1.4.min.js", "background.js" ],
    "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
  }]
}
```

### Popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Background Page</title>

      <style>
        #tidy, #tidy img {
            width:300px;
/*          max-width:300px; */
            min-height: 100px;
        }
        #ogImageHere{
            width:100%;
        }    
    </style>
  </head>


  <body>
    <div id="tidy">

                <div id="ogSiteNameHere"></div>
                <div id="ogTypeHere"></div>
                <div id="ogURLHere"></div>
                <div id="ogImageHere" width=100%></div>
                <div id="ogTitleHere"></div>
                <div id="ogDescriptionHere"></div>
                <div id="ogImageHere"></div>
                <div id="ogImageSecureURLHere"></div>
                <div id="ogTypeHere"></div>
                <div id="ogWidthHere"></div>
                <div id="ogHeightHere"></div>
                <div id="printHere"></div>

    </div>




    <script src='background.js'></script>


  </body>

</html>
```

### Background.js

```
var ogSiteName=jQuery("meta[property='og:site_name']").attr("content");
    jQuery("#ogSiteNameHere").html('<p>Here is the site name: '+ogSiteName+'</p>');
var ogType=jQuery("meta[property='og:type']").attr("content");
    jQuery("#ogTypeHere").html('<p>Here is the type: '+ogType+'</p>');
var ogURL=jQuery("meta[property='og:url']").attr("content");
    jQuery("#ogURLHere").html('<p>Here is the URL: '+ogURL+'</p>');
var ogImage=jQuery("meta[property='og:image']").attr("content");
    jQuery("#ogImageHere").html('<img src='+ogImage+' />').css("width","100%");
var ogTitle=jQuery("meta[property='og:title']").attr("content");
    jQuery("#ogTitleHere").html('<p>Here is the title: '+ogTitle+'</p>');
var ogDescription=jQuery("meta[property='og:description']").attr("content");
    jQuery("#ogDescriptionHere").html('<p>Here is the description: '+ogDescription+' </p>');
var ogImage=jQuery("meta[property='og:image']").attr("content");
    jQuery("#ogImageHere").html('<p>Here is the image</p> <p><img src='+ogImage+' /></p>');
var ogImageSecureURL=jQuery("meta[property='image:secure_url']").attr("content");
    jQuery("#ogImageSecureURLHere").html('<p>Here is the image secure URL:'+ogImageSecureURL+' </p> <p><img src='+ogImageSecureURL+' /></p>');
var ogImageType=jQuery("meta[property='og:image:type']").attr("content");
    jQuery("#ogImageTypeHere").html('<p>Here is the image</p> <p>'+ogImageType+'</p>');
var ogImageWidth=jQuery("meta[property='og:image:width']").attr("content");
    jQuery("#ogImageWidthHere").html('<p>Here is the image width '+ogImageWidth+' </p>');
var ogImageHeight=jQuery("meta[property='og:image:height']").attr("content");
    jQuery("#ogImageHeightHere").html('<p>Here is the image height: '+ogImageHeight+'px.</p>');

//THIS ALERT WORKS
alert('it partly works!');

//THIS PREPENDED IMAGE WORKS
jQuery("body").prepend('<img src="http://www.catgifpage.com/ui/images/grumpy.png">');
```

### popup.js

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById('commentsbutton').addEventListener('click', addOGInfo);  
});
```

Comment: You didn't add jquery in your page. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320200/jquery-usage-in-background-page-of-chrome-extension

Comment: btw, you don;t need jquery to do this.

Comment: Thanks @RaúlMartín - am working my way through this now. Can you let me know the other alternative to jquery you have in mind?

Comment: jQuery("#ogImageHeightHere").html can be document.getElmementBtId(..).innerHTML=  but you have another error concept. in the background.js you can not access to the document in the current tab.

Comment: Thank you @RaúlMartín . So to address that error concept, do I shift the javascript to popup.html or create a new file titled popup.js?

Comment: you should use a content_script in order to do that.

Comment: @scaffolding have you solved it

Comment: Hi @EdathadanChiefakaArun - yep I solved it. Apologies that this is so vague but I followed Raul's guidance and also Google's Chrome extension guidance. I hope that helps but if not please send word